# Creating a fixture list logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with some logic on trying to create a fixtures table for a football season. I have the teams set up automatically and each team needs to play each other home and away. I tried a very complicated logic seen on the net and tried to manipulate it but I keep receiving empty results, so I'm thinking of scrapping the logic and starting again.

Below is my 'Team' table:

```
TeamID  TeamAbbreviation   TeamName             LeagueID CountryID
1       MNU                Manchester United    1        1
2       CHE                Chelsea              1        1
3       LIV                Liverpool            1        1
4       ARS                Arsenal              1        1
```

Below is the fixtures table setup where at the moment I want to populate the fixture week (round of matches) and the teams to play each other.

```
[FixtureID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
[WeekNumber] INT NOT NULL, 
[HomeTeamID] INT CONSTRAINT FK_Fixture_HomeTeam FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Team](TeamID),
[AwayTeamID] INT CONSTRAINT FK_Fixture_AwayTeam FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Team](TeamID), 
[LeagueID] INT CONSTRAINT FK_Fixture_League FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES League(LeagueID)
```

Below is the logic I tried but failed as displaying an empty table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Fixture_Insert]

    @HomeTeamID INT,
    @AwayTeamID INT,
    @FixtureDate DATE,
        @FixtureTime TIME,
        @LeagueID INT,
        @SeasonID INT

    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @Rounds INT

    SELECT @Rounds = count(*) 
    FROM dbo.Team
        IF @Rounds % 2 = 0 
        SET @Rounds = @Rounds - 1

    DECLARE @Matches INT
    SET @Matches = (@Rounds + 1)/2
    DECLARE @Match INT
    DECLARE @Max_Team INT

    SELECT @Max_Team = count(*) 
    FROM dbo.Team

    DECLARE @BotLeft INT
    DECLARE @BotRight INT
    DECLARE @TopRight INT

    --Truncate Table Fixture
    DECLARE @Round INT
    SET @Round = 1
    WHILE @Round <=  @Rounds
    BEGIN
          SET @Match = 1
          WHILE @Match <= @Matches
          BEGIN
                SET @BotLeft = @Rounds/2.0 + 1.25 + @Match - @Round / 2.0
                SET @BotRight = @Rounds/2.0 + @Rounds + 2.75 - @Match - @Round / 2.0
                SET @TopRight = @Rounds - @Match - @Round + 3.0
                IF @topRight > @match
                BEGIN
                      SET @HomeTeamID = @Match
                      SET @AwayTeamID = @TopRight
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                      IF @BotRight = @Rounds + 1 AND @BotLeft = @Match * 2 - 1
                      BEGIN
                            SET @HomeTeamID = @Match
                            SET @AwayTeamID = @Rounds + 1
                      END
                      ELSE
                      BEGIN
                      IF @BotLeft = @BotRight
                            BEGIN
                                  SET @HomeTeamID = @BotLeft
                                  SET @AwayTeamID = @Rounds + 1
                            END
                            ELSE
                            BEGIN
                                  SET @HomeTeamID = @BotLeft
                                  SET @AwayTeamID = @BotRight

                            END

                      END
                END
                IF @AwayTeamID <= @Max_Team and @HomeTeamID <> @AwayTeamID
                INSERT INTO dbo.Fixture (WeekNumber, FixtureDate, FixtureTime, HomeTeamID, HomeScore, AwayTeamID, AwayScore, HomePoints, AwayPoints, LeagueID, SeasonID)
                VALUES (@Round, '10-10-2016', '12:00:00', @HomeTeamID, 2, @AwayTeamID, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1)
                SET @Match = @Match + 1
          END
          SET @Round = @Round + 1
    END

    --- insert home/away swaps
    INSERT INTO dbo.Fixture(WeekNumber, FixtureDate, FixtureTime, HomeTeamID, HomeScore, AwayTeamID, AwayScore, HomePoints, AwayPoints, LeagueID, SeasonID)
    SELECT @Round, '10-10-2016', '12:00:00', @HomeTeamID, 2, @AwayTeamID, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1 
    FROM dbo.Fixture

    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made this way more complicated than need be - you simply want to [`CROSS JOIN`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx) your team table with itself where the teamId's do not match (ie, a team cannot play itself).

Simplified example:

```
WITH team (teamId, teamName)
AS
(
    SELECT 1,'Manchester United'
    UNION SELECT 2,'Chelsea'
    UNION SELECT 3,'Liverpool'
    UNION SELECT 4,'Arsenal'
)

SELECT
    a.teamId as homeTeamId,
    a.teamName as homeTeam,
    b.teamId as awayTeamId,
    b.teamName as awayTeam
FROM team a
CROSS JOIN team b
WHERE a.teamId != b.teamId
```

Note that it's not immediately clear how you calculate `weekNumber` but I'd suggest that you look at [ranking functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189798.aspx)