# How to code a certain maths algorithm

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have been kindly given this algorithm to help me create a fixture list in SQL, but applying it as SQL code, I have no idea how to do. Is there a way somebody can guide me on how to apply it with code?

Below is my tables schema and below that is the algorithm:

League:

```
[LeagueID] TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
[LeagueName] VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE
```

Team:

```
[TeamID] TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
[TeamAbbreviation] CHAR(3) UNIQUE, 
[TeamName] VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE, 
[LeagueID] TINYINT CONSTRAINT FK_Team_League FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES League(LeagueID)
```

Fixture:

```
[FixtureID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[WeekNumber] INT NOT NULL,
[FixtureDate] DATE NULL,
[HomeTeamID] TINYINT NULL,
[AwayTeamID] TINYINT NULL,
[LeagueID] TINYINT CONSTRAINT FK_Fixture_League FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES League(LeagueID)
```

ALGORITHM:

Lets us translate the algorithm, called [round robin scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm), in terms of an ordered list `l` of N teams (which correspond to N-1 polygon vertices + the polygon center):

- `l` defines fixtures by playing the first team from the list against the last, the second against the first before last, etc.
  That is, for `0 ≤ x < N`, you play team `l[x]` vs team `l[N-1-x]`.
- To generate the next set of fixtures, you rotate the `N-1` first elements of the list.
  That is `l = l[1] + l[2] + ... + l[N-2] + l[0] + l[N-1]`
- Once you've done the full set of `N-1` rotations, do it again but swapping home and away teams: play team `l[N-1-x]` vs team `l[x]` instead of the opposite.

If you start with the numerically ordered list `0..N-1` then at round `i` the list is:
`l = [(i + 0) % (N-1)] +  [(i + 1) % (N-1)] + ... +  [(i + N-2) % (N-1)] + [N-1]`

That is, **fixtures are at round `i`:**

- **`i` vs `N-1`**
- For `0 < x < (N-1) / 2`, **`(x + i) % (N-1)` vs `(N-1 - x + i) % (N-1)`**

Now there is a trick, as this **only works for even numbers.** Otherwise the last team always plays (against team `i` at round `i`) whereas naturally each round has one team that can't play. That would mean team 4 plays one more game than the other teams.

To solve this, we **add a dummy team,** so for 5 teams we have `N = 6`, and at round `i`:

- `i` vs `5` (the dummy team)
- `(i + 1) % 4` vs `(4 + i) % 4`
- `(i + 2) % 4` vs `(3 + i) % 4`

Now that you know this, you can generate a function that will give you fixtures based on round number. It should output the following:

> round 0: 0 rests, 1 vs 4, 2 vs 3
>   round 1: 1 rests, 2 vs 0, 3 vs 4
>   round 2: 2 rests, 3 vs 1, 4 vs 0
>   round 3: 3 rests, 4 vs 2, 0 vs 1
>   round 4: 4 rests, 0 vs 3, 1 vs 2

---

Note that instead of `i` in the formulas `x + i` and `N-1 - x + i` you can use any multiple `m * i` (so `x + m * i` and `N-1 - x + m * i`) as long as `m` and `N-1` and [relatively prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relatively_prime). Here `N - 1 = 5`  is prime, so you can use any `m` you want.

**UPDATE:**

As required below is thee test data for first the League table and second the teams table (matching the table schema columns in order)

League:

```
1, 'English Premiership'
2, 'English Division 1'
```

Teams:

```
1, 'BCN', 'FC Barcelona', 1
2, 'MAD', 'Real Madrid', 1
3, 'ATH', 'Athletico Madrid', 1
4, 'ESP', 'Espanyol', 1
5, 'MAN', 'Manchester United', 2
6, 'BOL', 'Bolton', 2
7, 'CHE', 'Chelsea', 2
8, 'ARS', 'Arsenal', 2
```

Teams play each other home and away and can only play against teams who are in the same league (hence the different LeagueIDs)

The matches should be like this for each round:

```
League 1:

Round 1- 01/05/2016:
1v4, 2v3

Round 2- 08/05/2016:
1v2, 3v4

Round 3- 15/05/2016:
3v1, 4v2

Round 4- 22/05/2016:
4v1, 3v2

Round 5- 29/05/2016:
2v1, 4v3

Round 6- 05/06/2016:
1v3, 2v4


League 2:

Round 1- 01/05/2016:
5v8, 6v7

Round 2- 08/05/2016:
5v6, 7v8

Round 3- 15/05/2016:
3v1, 4v2

Round 4- 22/05/2016:
8v5, 7v6

Round 5- 29/05/2016:
6v5, 8v7

Round 6- 05/06/2016:
5v7, 6v8
```

- League number is 'LeagueID'
- Round number is 'WeekNumber'
- Date is 'Fixture Date'
- Home team number is 'HomeTeamID'
- Away team number is 'AwayTeamID'

This should all be inserted in the 'Fixture' table.

Comment: Now that's how a question should be asked.

Comment: just linking to you previous related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610060/creating-a-fixture-list-logic

Comment: @Tanner Cool, yeah the problem with that previous approach was even though it displayed the teams correctly, it had trouble displaying the correct week numbers per round of matches. This way using an algorithm will help solve the week issue but it is a completely new and more mathematic route

Comment: @RyanVincent I've included the test data and displayed expected results which will need to be placed in the 'Fixture' table. Check 'UPDATE' section and let me know if it's ok or if your require anything else.

Comment: Thank you - excellent question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another Oracle solution.

**Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE League (
  LeagueID   INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  LeagueName VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Team (
  TeamID           INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  TeamAbbreviation CHAR(3) UNIQUE, 
  TeamName         VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE, 
  LeagueID         INT CONSTRAINT FK_Team_League REFERENCES League(LeagueID) 
);

CREATE TABLE Fixture (
  FixtureID   INT PRIMARY KEY,
  WeekNumber  INT NOT NULL,
  FixtureDate DATE NULL,
  HomeTeamID  INT NULL,
  AwayTeamID  INT NULL,
  LeagueID    INT CONSTRAINT FK_Fixture_League REFERENCES League(LeagueID)
);

INSERT INTO League VALUES ( 1, 'League 1' );
INSERT INTO League VALUES ( 2, 'League 2' );

INSERT INTO Team VALUES ( 1, 'AAA', 'Team A', 1 );
INSERT INTO Team VALUES ( 2, 'BBB', 'Team B', 1 );
INSERT INTO Team VALUES ( 3, 'CCC', 'Team C', 1 );
INSERT INTO Team VALUES ( 4, 'DDD', 'Team D', 1 );
INSERT INTO Team VALUES ( 5, 'EEE', 'Team E', 2 );
INSERT INTO Team VALUES ( 6, 'FFF', 'Team F', 2 );
INSERT INTO Team VALUES ( 7, 'GGG', 'Team G', 2 );
INSERT INTO Team VALUES ( 8, 'HHH', 'Team H', 2 );
INSERT INTO Team VALUES ( 9, 'III', 'Team I', 2 );
```

**Insert - Fixtures**:

```
INSERT INTO Fixture
WITH league_teams ( id, leagueid, idx, is_fake, num_teams, num_fake ) AS (
  -- Generate a unique-per-league index for each team that is between 0
  -- and the (number of teams - 1) and calculate the number of teams
  -- and if this is an odd number then generate a fake team as well.
  SELECT TeamID,
         LeagueID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY LeagueID ORDER BY TeamID ) - 1,
         0,
         COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY LeagueID ),
         MOD( COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY LeagueID ), 2 )
  FROM Team
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL,
         LeagueID,
         COUNT(1),
         1,
         COUNT(1),
         1
  FROM   Team
  GROUP BY LeagueID
  HAVING MOD( COUNT(1), 2 ) > 0
),
cte ( home_idx, away_idx, week_number, leagueID, num_teams, num_fake ) AS (
  -- Start by calculating the round 1 games
  SELECT idx,
         num_teams + num_fake - 1 - idx,
         1,
         LeagueID,
         num_teams,
         num_fake
  FROM   league_teams
  WHERE  2 * idx < num_teams
UNION ALL
  -- Then generate the successive rounds with the two cases when the
  -- away team has the maximum index or otherwise.
  SELECT CASE away_idx
           WHEN num_teams + num_fake - 1
           THEN home_idx + 1
           ELSE MOD( home_idx + 1, num_teams + num_fake -1 )
           END,
         CASE away_idx
           WHEN num_teams + num_fake - 1
           THEN away_idx
           ELSE MOD( away_idx + 1, num_teams + num_fake - 1 )
           END,
        week_number + 1,
        LeagueID,
        num_teams,
        num_fake
  FROM  cte
  WHERE week_number < num_teams + num_fake - 1
)
-- Finally join the cte results back to the League_Teams table to convert
-- the indexes used in calculation back to the actual team ids.
SELECT rn,
       week_number,
       NULL,
       h.id,
       a.id,
       c.leagueid
FROM   (
         -- This step isn't necessary but it keeps the results in a nice order.
         SELECT ROWNUM AS rn,
                t.*
         FROM   (
           -- Duplicate the results swapping home and away.
           SELECT week_number,
                  home_idx,
                  away_idx,
                  LeagueId
           FROM   cte
           UNION ALL
           SELECT week_number + num_teams + num_fake - 1,
                  away_idx,
                  home_idx,
                  LeagueId
           FROM   cte
         ) t
       ) c
       INNER JOIN League_Teams h
       ON ( c.home_idx = h.idx AND c.leagueId = h.leagueID )
       INNER JOIN League_Teams a
       ON ( c.away_idx = a.idx AND c.leagueId = a.leagueID )
ORDER BY rn;
```

**Output**:

```
SELECT * FROM fixture;

 FIXTUREID WEEKNUMBER FIXTUREDATE         HOMETEAMID AWAYTEAMID   LEAGUEID
---------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1                              1          4          1 
         2          1                              2          3          1 
         3          1                              5                     2 
         4          1                              6          9          2 
         5          1                              7          8          2 
         6          2                              2          4          1 
         7          2                              3          1          1 
         8          2                              6                     2 
         9          2                              7          5          2 
        10          2                              8          9          2 
        11          3                              3          4          1 
        12          3                              1          2          1 
        13          3                              7                     2 
        14          3                              8          6          2 
        15          3                              9          5          2 
        16          4                              8                     2 
        17          4                              9          7          2 
        18          4                              5          6          2 
        19          5                              9                     2 
        20          5                              5          8          2 
        21          5                              6          7          2 
        22          4                              4          1          1 
        23          4                              3          2          1 
        24          6                                         5          2 
        25          6                              9          6          2 
        26          6                              8          7          2 
        27          5                              4          2          1 
        28          5                              1          3          1 
        29          7                                         6          2 
        30          7                              5          7          2 
        31          7                              9          8          2 
        32          6                              4          3          1 
        33          6                              2          1          1 
        34          8                                         7          2 
        35          8                              6          8          2 
        36          8                              5          9          2 
        37          9                                         8          2 
        38          9                              7          9          2 
        39          9                              6          5          2 
        40         10                                         9          2 
        41         10                              8          5          2 
        42         10                              7          6          2
```

*(Note: `FixtureDate` is `NULL` since it is unclear how you want this generated but you should be able to take the week number and use this as the offset from the start of the season to generate dates)*

Comment: Cool MT0, I will give this a go when I have chance and let you know the outcome. If I get it working then I'll post the SQL Server solution. Thank you

Comment: Hi Mt0, Given you best answer as I trust yuor oracle version will work. Been trying last couple of hours to convert using SQL Server but haven't been successful. I will post another question to see if anyone can convert it to sql server code and link this question to that question to help those dealing with SQL server. Thank you very much :)

Comment: The SQL Server answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746092/converting-oracle-code-to-sql-server-for-a-fixture-list, Thank you for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to get what you want -- but this is Oracle SQL (I have no access to a SQL server DB at the moment).  But I believe all you need to change is the MOD function, the text concatenation, and the reference to DUAL to get it working on SQL Server:

```
WITH TEAMS(TEAMID,TEAMNAME) AS (
SELECT 0,'TEAM A' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 1,'TEAM B' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 2,'TEAM C' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 3,'TEAM D' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT 4,'TEAM E' FROM DUAL 
),
TEAMSX(TEAMID,TEAMNAME) AS (
SELECT * FROM TEAMS
UNION
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEAMS) TEAMID,'DUMMY' FROM DUAL WHERE MOD((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEAMS),2)<>0),
TEAM_FIX(ROUND,TEAMID,FIXID) AS (
SELECT 0,TEAMID,TEAMID FROM TEAMSX
UNION ALL
SELECT ROUND+1,TEAMID,
  CASE WHEN TEAMID=(SELECT COUNT(*)-1 FROM TEAMSX) THEN (SELECT COUNT(*)-1 FROM TEAMSX) ELSE 
  MOD(TEAMID+(ROUND+1),(SELECT COUNT(*)-1 FROM TEAMSX)) END FROM TEAM_FIX
WHERE ROUND < (SELECT COUNT(*)-2 FROM TEAMSX))
SELECT ROUND, TXT FROM (
SELECT TEAM1.ROUND,TEAM1.FIXID TM1,TEAM2.FIXID TM2, 
CASE WHEN TX.TEAMNAME='DUMMY' THEN TEAM1.FIXID || ' rests' ELSE TEAM1.FIXID || ' vs ' || TEAM2.FIXID END TXT FROM 
TEAM_FIX TEAM1
JOIN TEAM_FIX TEAM2 ON (TEAM1.ROUND=TEAM2.ROUND AND TEAM1.TEAMID+TEAM2.TEAMID=(SELECT COUNT(*)-1 FROM TEAMSX) AND TEAM1.TEAMID < TEAM2.TEAMID)
JOIN TEAMSX TX ON (TEAM2.TEAMID=TX.TEAMID)
ORDER BY TEAM1.ROUND,TEAM1.TEAMID)
```

The first WITH table (TEAMS) is just to create some sample data.

The second table (TEAMSX) will create a dummy team if we have an odd number of teams.

The third table (TEAM_FIX) is a recursive CTE that uses the function you gave to generate the proper list ordering for each round.

Then in the main query, we join TEAM_FIX against itself for each round to create team matchups.

Comment: Cool Mike, I will give it a go when I have time and let you know the outcome. Thank you